# How do I match two or more numbers in a dialplan?

Tags: pattern-matching, asterisk, voip

I have two DID numbers I want to forward to the same IVR on inbound calls:

- 1234
- 4321

How can I do this? I've tried:

```
exten => ^(1234|4321),1,Answer()
```

but it does not work - it cannot find the extension and falls to the catchall trap. 
It basically does not match and this part of my dialplan, placed at the bottom, is executed:

```
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
exten => _X.,2,agi(googletts.agi,"No extension found",en)
exten => _X.,3,Hangup()
```

Using a single number instead of that expression works just fine. Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe what you see when it does not work?

Comment: Yes, it falls through to this:
`exten => _X.,1,Answer()`
`exten => _X.,2,agi(googletts.agi,"No extension found",en)`
`exten => _X.,3,Hangup()`

Comment: It basically executes the trap for no extension found. Entering a single number works fine though, so the expression must be the problem.

Comment: Cool, you might want to edit your question to include that output as well.

Comment: One more thing, what language is this code written in? I don't recognize it, but whatever language you're using should be tagged on this post. Right now you just have pattern-matching, asterisk, and voip which is a bit too general and might not get picked up by any of the experts in that language on SO.

Comment: 2Jason It is asterisk dialplan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk dialplan is not fully compliant with GNU regexp

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Dialplan+Patterns

There are no "or"(|) operation in asterisk dialplan. Recommended way do something like this

```
[incoming]
exten => 1234,1,Goto(special_routine,s,1)
exten => 4321,1,Goto(special_routine,s,1)
include =>other; include other context, have less priority
[special_routine]
exten => s,1,Answer; do something for both numbers
[other];do this if no extension
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,2,agi(googletts.agi,"No extension found",en)
exten => s,3,Hangup()
```

Comment: Okay, I'll implement it this way. Thanks